How to set cookie in Flutter Web with specific domain?
As referenced from another question:
Is there a way to create and read cookies in Flutter Web?
I tried implementing domain into the function similar with:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie
Thus with the function:
document.cookie = 'cookie_name=$cookie_value; domain=$mydomain';

However, when I run this function, it does not set cookie properly. Without the domain suffix, it works, but I required the domain to be another path.
I noticed that it doesn't work due to security reasons for cross-domain. However, I wanted it to be a subdomain of my web DNS which is still in the same domain, just different subdomains, for example:
My website: website.samedomain.com
Setting the cookie: *.session.samedomain.com

I also tried using flutter_inappwebview package which works on Android/IOS when setting cookie with CookieManager instance with the example below, but does not set the cookie on Flutter Web.
CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.instance();
await cookieManager.setCookie(
        url: WebUri('http://$domain'), name: "cookie", value: value);

Is there any way to solve this issue? Or are there any other work around?

Simply use below format,
var mydomain = '.samedomain.com'; // it accepts both 'website' and 'session' cookies 
document.cookie = 'cookie_name=$cookie_value; domain=$mydomain';

if you use cookies from server like node/express js, use below
const cors = require('cors');

app.use(cors({
    origin: ["https://yourapidomain.com"],
    methods: ["GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"],
    credentials : true // allows cookies
}));

var session = {
   name: "COOKIE_NAME",
   cookie : {
      domain: '.samedomain.com',
      maxAge: 3600000,
      httpOnly: true
   },
   secret: "SECRET_VALUE"
}

